# running a python script in the command line from any directory

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, executable

apologies in advance for a naive question! i've been doing some digging on here and still feel a bit confused.

i have a python script that i'd like to make executable from anywhere in a bash shell (like how `git`, `homebrew`, `neofetch`, etc. can all be called). i've used `pyinstall` to make an executable, but i don't quite know what to do with this. i tried moving the build folder to `usr/local` and putting an alias for the executable in `usr/local/bin`, but i got a 'cannot execute binary file' error when trying to run from the shell. i tried this after referencing the 'git' alias in `urs/local/bin`, and seeing that it directed to an executable in the `usr/local`.

does anyone know of any suggestions, or know of any good resources to try and understand what i'm doing wrong? thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple script, the easiest way to make it executable is to simply add a Python [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), save the script to a directory that's on your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`) and set the executable bit on the script.

E.g.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
print('Hello, world! I am Python', sys.version)
```

saved as `/usr/local/bin/python-hello` followed by `chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/python-hello` will let you execute `python-hello` from anywhere.

More complex scripts are best made executable by [packaging them correctly](https://packaging.python.org/) with a proper [`console_scripts` entry point](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/)  -- though something packed with PyInstaller would also work, although it'd be much heavier.

## EDIT

A script with multiple modules should be organized into a package, e.g.

```
python_hello/
  __init__.py
  __main__.py
  greetings.py
```

`__main__.py` could then look like

```
def main():
    # ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way you can run the script with `python -m python_hello` as well as set up `python_hello.__main__:main` as a console script entry point.

Comment: this is super helpful. if i have several modules, is there a 'correct' way to organize them? and if i do want to use this packed with pyinstaller, am i making a silly mistake? i'm confused as to why placing the build folder in `usr/local`, creating an alias for the exe, and placing it in `usr/local/bin` doesn't function as intended. thanks a bunch!

Comment: Are you using usr/local (the usr directory is relative to and under your current directory) or /usr/local, which is a system directory that is in your $PATH?

Comment: @sevenr /usr/local

Comment: @joooby Added an explanation about packages :)